# Errno 2: No such file or directory: SSLError while calling s3.get_object()

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm trying to load a csv file from my S3 bucket through my lambda function.
I get following error when I do so.

```
Errno 2: No such file or directory: SSLError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function_csv.py", line 12, in lambda_handler
obj = raw_s3.get_object(Bucket ='h2h-demo', Key ='H2H_results_100.csv')
```

Im using the code given below in my function to get the file. When use the inline editor in the function configuration to create a small function that prints out the rows of the csv file Im reading it works.

This is also working when I run it on my local machine.

```
raw_s3 = boto3.client('s3')
obj = raw_s3.get_object(Bucket ='h2h-demo', Key ='H2H_results_100.csv')
```

However when I put it in my final code which is being zipped with some other dependencies and is using the row data for other processing I get the error stated above.
I dont understand why this is happening .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only copy objects into tmp folder on lambda, make the following changes by adding a tmp folder to the destination:
    `obj = raw_s3.get_object(Bucket ='h2h-demo', Key ='/tmp/H2H_results_100.csv')`

I would suggest to throw exceptions in the future they are really useful in debugging:

```
 import boto3
 import botocore

BUCKET_NAME = 'xyz' # replace with your bucket name
KEY = 'xyz' # replace with your object key

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

try:
    s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME).download_file(KEY, '/tmp/xyz')
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        print("The object does not exist.")
    else:
        raise
```

If you try to save it in lambda other than tmp folder you will get the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "[Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'xyz'",
```

Reference:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-example-download-file.html